# Match Regex Starting After "X" Number of Characters

Tags: regex, google-apps-script

I am using regex in a Google script to normalize company names, and while I am getting very close to perfect with a combination of replacing certain words, punctuation, and spaces, my last step was to replace any word with 3 or fewer letters.

But that gets rid of a few companies with acronyms at the start of their name, ie AB Holding Company. I don't want this to match AB, I want it to find the rare "the", or company code (particularly foreign ones like SPA and NV along with Co and Inc). These codes are not necessarily at the end of the string, but they seem to always be at least 4 characters after the beginning.

I am currently using

```
text = text.replace(/\b[a-z]{1,3}\b)/i," ");
```

*Ignore the [a-z] as missing caps, I've dealt with that separately*

What I think would work is to "skip over" the first few characters, probably 4 to be safe, and maybe learn how to include spaces and/or digits in there for the future. So I wrote this after seeing 1 other related question here.

```
text = text.replace(/((.{4})(.*)\b[a-z]{1,3}\b)/i," ");
```

Scipts does not seem to allow a lookbehind, and my version doesn't seem to work. I'm lost.

I appreciate your help.

Comment: Please provide sample strings to test against and expected output. Also let us know if any of these company names use/could use non-Latin characters.

Comment: Please checkout [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution:

```
 text = text.replace("/^(.{4}.*)(\b[a-z]{1,3}\b)(.*)/gmi", "$1$3");
```

What I have changed is:

- enclosed all groups in parenthesis - so that they can be captured and used in the replacement;
- since you mentioned that the word-to-be-replaced might not be in the end of the string, I also added a third group - to match everything after.
- included the part before and after the word in the replacement string (group 1 and group 3).

However, note that it might return false positives - i.e. if a company name is Company ABC, Inc., it will also capture ABC. Thus, if you know the words you want to replace, it might be better to just use an alteration:

```
text = text.replace("/^(.{4}.*)\b(Co|Inc|SPA|NV|the)\b(.*)/gmi", "$1$3");
```

Comment: your alternation `(\bCo|Inc|SPA|NV|the\b)` will only require the word bounary before `Co` and after `the` - I suggest putting the word boundaries outside the parens like `\b(Co|Inc|SPA|NV|the)\b`

Comment: The above works great. I had considered adding the codes like in your second example, but there are too many variations to make that worthwhile. I have not encountered any problems like your "Company ABC" concern. Thank you for your help.